# JavaScript automated tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, teamcity

I would like to automate the running of unit test as a part of integration process. Is it possible to automate running of JavaScript unit tests in TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is posible to run unit test in some standalone JS test runner. I preffer the [JS test driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/).

I have also custom test runner based on top of NUnit and Selenium for running Google Closure JSUnit suites ant it works well with TeamCity.

Comment: We have been using jasmine and maven jasmine plugin